# Can not call python from subprocess in a pyinstaller exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, subprocess, pyinstaller

i write a code that works fine. So i created an exe file with pyinstaller. here comes the problem

```
import subprocess
import requests
requests.get('url..')
print('something')
subprocess.Popen('python script.py')
```

This last line Popen causing problem.
So i made my exe and it working on those computers who have python installed and configured at path. But if i run my exe on a computer which dont have python installed only the requests.get and print commands are working.
so the problem is if i call `python` with subprocess then subprocess search the python command in the host pc not in the exe which have python39.dll file or interpreter.
And i don't have any way to use the script.py file in my script
I have to run that script.py file in command line because script.py relays on command line arguments.
I have to pass script.py like
`>>>python script.py 80 halo`
So i use subprocess to run the command from my script.but this causing the problem that this requires python to be installed for running the script.py
Any help or suggestions are welcome.i am new here so if i made any mistake please comment. By the way i use pagekite.py instead of the script.py from pagekite.net.
Pagekite.py only runs in command line as i know. If you know any workaround please help.
Thanks for your time and help.
You can ask me if you have any doubt or questions.

Comment: A PyInstaller exe doesn’t install Python, as you have found. Not sure why that’s a surprise. Anyway maybe you can solve this by including the functionality you want to invoke using subprocess within the exe so you build it into your exe perhaps so it can be run by a commandline option that your exe identifies and calls whatever function you want to invoke. So if your program is myprog.exe, maybe invoking it as `myprog -subproc` And the `-subproc` option makes your code run `script.py` (or a function in it)

Comment: Very sorry but this is not clear to me. How i supply command line arguments to script.py? I cannot change or make the script.py . You can check pagekite.py which i use in my code at pagekite.net

Comment: You’ll supply commandline argument to your existing exe - and add decoding the commandline arg in your `main` in your exe. Don’t know the specifics of pagekite.py, can you invoke it from a python script (i.e. not using subprocess)? Can you import pagekite.py and call a function from it?

Comment: No i cannot because the pagekite.py usees zlib encoding to secure the code there are no function i think but you can download and and give it a try.

Comment: Err, no thanks; it’s your problem, not mine. But there must be some Python code in pagekite.py? You should change thetitle of your question to your real problem, something like: “How can I invoke pagekite.py directly from another Python script?”

Comment: Minimal research finds PyPageKite - I’m sure you can find it if you try. Who knows, maybe it would help. Good luck!